# Magento Volume Weight (Global Attribute) not saving/updating

Tags: magento

I have a global attribute in Magento, volume_weight which is not saving via the admin control panel. I have no idea why, no matter what store view I use, it is not saving.

Any ideas where to start looking for the problem? I think it started when I used Magmi importer, and imported volume weight into different store views - but it's a global attribute ?!

Please help!

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Take one product, clean the database. And check, whether this helps. Magento checks itself for integrity, but if you have storeview-specific attributes, they may overwrite your global settings and you can't edit them inside of magento, because it is a global attribute ;)

Comment: if your attribute has scope "global" then magmi would only affect it's value to "default values" (ie admin store), so no "store value" would exist for it since this attribute cannot be set with "store scope" vales as it is global.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

you need to identify the attribute ids for all global attributes then delete all the values from the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables that have the attribute id one of those identified above and the store id field not zero.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
WHERE
   store_id <> 0 AND
   attribute_id IN (
           SELECT attribute_id 
           FROM catalog_eav_attribute 
           WHERE is_global = 1

   )
```

Do the same for the tables `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

Rebuild your indexes when your are done.

Note: The select from `catalog_eav_attribute` in the way I wrote it will give you attribute ids for the global category attributes also, but that's not important since in the product tables you don't have category attributes references.

Also, before trying this, backup your database in case I missed something.

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42763/6501
Thanks to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius